# Size differences of xml files on ftp server and on s3

Tags: python, xml, amazon-s3, ftp

I've a ton (about 20k) of large-ish xml files which currently exist on an FTP server, but I'm moving to s3.

At this point, all files have been moved to s3, and I'm *just about* ready to delete them from the FTP server, but before doing so, I was running a few quick "size" checks on both sides, to make sure we're good.

Everything's done in Python, with `ftplib` handling the FTP calls (I have checked what it's doing and reading is correct with my normal FTP GUI client), and `boto` for the s3 side.

About 15k of these files, there's *no* size difference, but on about 5k, there can be anything from 5B size in difference, to `16283276B/16MB` (that's the largest difference I saw on a file that's `29055138B/29MB` on the FTP server, but `12771862B/12MB` on s3).

I didn't upload with any compression, and the funny thing is, if I go onto s3, even though the files are different in size, the file is completely there.  When I open up the file, because it's an XML, it's easy enough to see that the opening and closing tag is there correctly, and it displays correctly with a XML browser plugin (which it doesn't do if there's some corruption).

So yeah, I'm not really sure what's going on, as these files were just downloaded from FTP, and uploaded to s3 on an Ubuntu server, and both "sets" of files seem fine in both places, but I don't understand the (sometimes quite large) file size differences.

To get the file size from ftp, I'm running a `DIR` command on the server, and parsing the line to get the size.

To download the file, I'm running the ftplib command,

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR {}'.format(source), open(dest, 'wb').write)
```

To upload the file to s3 (due to a timeout bug on boto and s3), I'm running the shell command,

```
aws s3 cp {source_path} {s3_path}
```

Comment: Use a checksum, sounds like they haven't been uploaded correctly.

Comment: Also don't forget that "size" and "size on disk" are two different things, and that (obviously) `1000 kb` is **NOT** `1 mb`, because it goes up in doubles, so `1024`

Comment: The MB I was writing was "fluffy", and just for ease of reading moreso than accuracy, the bytes figure is there for anyone needing the exact size.  Re: checksum, I certainly could do that, but with this amount of files, on a not-so-fast FTP server, and s3 which isn't super fast for this stuff, that would take a serious amount of time. And I have manually checked a few of these files with difference, and there hasn't been a single difference I've found between them yet - hence my confusion.